# Why is my angular module not seeing this var passed from php?

Tags: angularjs

I am using this package to pass php into javascript.

[laracasts/utilities](https://packagist.org/packages/laracasts/utilities)

I have installed as per the instructions.

I have this in my controller;

```
use Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptFacade as JavaScript;

public function quiz()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    JavaScript::put([
        'profile' => $user
    ]);

    return View::make ('quiz');
}
```

Here is my view;

```
<div ng-app="quiz"
     ng-controller="QuizController"
     ng-cloak>

    This quiz goes here...
    @include('footer')
    <div class="row">
        <script>console.log(app.profile);</script>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre>
            <code>Profile: @{{ profile.name | json }}</code>
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then my js

```
var app = angular.module('quiz', []);

app.controller('QuizController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.profile = app.profile;

console.log(app.profile);

}]);
```

Now the really odd thing.

When I console.log app.profile in the view it works.  I see the object as expected.  However, both the console.log in the js and the output into the `<pre>` tag are returning undefined.

How is that?

Answer (score 0):

Grrrrrr...

This seem ridiculous and sorry to answer my own question but evidently you can't use the same namespace for your vars in the javascript config as you use for the name of your app.

app & app no dice.

app and quiz - works.

Hope this helps someone else who might get stumped on this simple snag.

Comment: More accurate - app is a 'reserved word'.